# Valores estranhos ao gerar array em um objeto dinâmico no PHP

Tags: php, array, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, dinâmico

Segue este código de exemplo:

```
class Object{
      private $keys = [];
      private $values = [];

      public function criarArray(){
           $obj=get_object_vars($this);

           foreach($obj as $key => $value):
                $this->keys[] = $key;
           endforeach;

           return $this->keys;
       }
}
```

Instanciando:

```
$var = new Object();
$var->descricao = "valor para coluna 1";
$var->preco = 22.1;
$var->data = date("Y-m-d");

var_dump($var->criarArray());
```

Temos esta saída:

```
array(5){
   [0]=>
   string(4) "keys"
   [1]=>
   string(5) "value"
   [2]=>
   string(9) "descricao"
   [3]=>
   string(5) "preco"
   [4]=>
   string(4) "data"
}
```

Enfim, de onde saíram as chaves [0]=> string(4) "keys" e  [1]=> string(5) "value"? Como faço para elimina-las?

Usar `unset($this->keys)` e `unset($this->values)` não é uma opção viável!

Comment: $obj=get_object_vars($this); Aqui é retornado os atributos da classe, por isso o keys e values.

Comment: Então @DiegoSchmidt, como manter somente os valores que passei?

Comment: Você quer  que não apareça isto ou que a variável não exista? Você precisa destas variáveis? Na verdade precisa disto, me parece que não. Precisa de uma classe? Também me parece que não.

Comment: @bigown. Preciso da classe e das variáveis. Não quero que apareçam.

Comment: Não entendi pq vc quer mata as propriedades da classe que guardam os respectivos chave e valor, um dicionario (vulgo array associativo) resolve ou apenas uma função simples.

Comment: @rray, não quero 'matar', por isso disse que unset() não é uma opção. Só quero guardar as chaves geradas sem guardar as variáveis!

Comment: O que está demonstrado aí não precisa de nada disto, acho mais fácil dizer qual o problema que quer resolver porque parece que esta não é a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei a finalizade do código, uma forma de pegar só as 'propriedades dinâmicas' e excluir as definidas na classe como `$keys` e `$values` é pegar o retorno de `get_object_vars()` e executar um `unset()` nas chaves desejadas.

```
class Object{
    private $keys = [];
    private $values = [];

    public function criarArray(){
        $obj=get_object_vars($this);

        //Código adicionado:

        unset($obj['keys']);
        unset($obj['values']);

        foreach($obj as $key => $value):
            $this->keys[] = $key;
        endforeach;

        return $this->keys;
    }
}

$var = new Object();
$var->descricao = "valor para coluna 1";
$var->preco = 22.1;
$var->data = date("Y-m-d");
```

Saida:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'descricao' (length=9)
  1 => string 'preco' (length=5)
  2 => string 'data' (length=4)
```

Se quiser montar uma versão mais incrementada pode pegar as propriedades definidas no corpo da classe e adicionar em uma nova (`privateFields`) isso deve ser feito no construtor. Depois pode fazer a diferença entre as chaves do array de `privateFields` e as propriedades dinâmicas.  `array_push` combinado com `...` substituem o foreach.

```
class Object{
    private $keys = [];
    private $values = [];
    private $privateFields = [];

    public function __construct(){
        $this->privateFields = get_object_vars($this);
    }


    public function criarArray(){
        $obj = array_diff_key(get_object_vars($this), $this->privateFields);
        array_push($this->keys, ...array_keys($obj));
        return $this->keys;
    }
}

$var = new Object();
$var->descricao = "valor para coluna 1";
$var->preco = 22.1;
$var->data = date("Y-m-d");

var_dump($var->criarArray());

$var->nova = 'outro valor';
$var->nome = 'fulano';

var_dump($var->criarArray());


Saida:


array (size=8)
  0 => string 'descricao' (length=9)
  1 => string 'preco' (length=5)
  2 => string 'data' (length=4)
  3 => string 'descricao' (length=9)
  4 => string 'preco' (length=5)
  5 => string 'data' (length=4)
  6 => string 'nova' (length=4)
  7 => string 'nome' (length=4)
```

Comment: Entendido, a solução foi o unset() do objeto. Perfeito.